# How do I identify the protocol (http vs. https) using Perl's CGI.pm

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm editing a Perl CGI application that does special processing when run under HTTPS.

Right now, I'm trying to detect it by manually looking for 'https://' in the request URI:

```
    my $is_secure = $cgi->request_uri =~ m{^https://};
```

Is there a slightly cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CGI.pm has an `https()` method that, according to [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html):

> operates on the HTTPS environment variables present when the SSL protocol is in effect. Can be used to determine whether SSL is turned on.

This is probably what you're looking for. Without parameters, it returns a list of HTTPS environment variables.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it was relevant to something I was looking for as well. Unfortunately, the documentation you linked to doesn't tell you how to do it, just that one can.

Answer (score 1):

Use $ENV{'HTTPS'}

```
my $is_secure = $ENV{'HTTPS'};
```

Or perhaps better, just use $ENV{'HTTPS'} instead of $is_secure

Comment: I'd expect most mainstream servers to have some environment variable for this even if it isn't exactly this.